# How to retrieve a default style with Expression Blend?

Tags: wpf, expression-blend

From what I know, Expression Blend is the only method to look at a default style for some WPF control. But I find it very unelegant to create a new project, find a directory to save it to, add the element to my empty window designer and find some hidden "edit template copy" command or so.

And it totally fails when I want to get a DataGridCell style because I can't add it to the window.

How is this really correctly and efficiently done?

If Expression Blend is not involved in the better solution, please go ahead and let me know. Something directly available from VS 2010 would be best.

Answer (score 0):

It's not the only method, but it is generally the easiest route since Blend by far makes for a better designing experience.

For you issue, I forget the names of the Default resource dictionaries for WPF. Like with SL you'd just go look into the CoreStyles, SDKStyles, ToolkitStyles (.xaml) files for the full templates. I'm pretty sure the same exists in WPF wherein you could likely locate them with a quick solution search for `TargetType="{blah}"` or wherever they're referenced to be loaded.

Otherwise you can continue with the right-click "Edit Template" method, and for a child part of a template (like a DataGridCell style) you would instead choose "Edit Additional Templates" and find that part of the template there the same way.

However like I said you can go straight to the templates themselves, just have to find the default dictionaries first. Hope this helps.

Comment: I have no idea about Silverlight (if that's what you mean by "SL"). Do you mean that these XAML files come with the .NET framework somewhere and I can find them on my computer already? Just search for *.xaml with a good content pattern?

Comment: Ya SL = Silverlight, but the differences in the XAML side of it generally aren't too significant except in a couple areas. I think what you're looking for could be found in more detail than one can offer in an SO post [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970773.aspx).

Comment: There we have all default styles for easy lookup with no tool. Great link!